# Autocomplete on very large mongodb tables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, autocomplete

I been looking into autocomplete on angular materials, and it works great as long as you load the entire table into your controller as an array.

But what if that table has 10,000 records? How would you do that?

I would like to search / autocomplete on my mongodb db.user table, and it looks something like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "this@that.com", 
    "name" : "This Thatson", 
    "phone" : "343-345-2234" 
},
{ 
    "_id" : "foo@bar.com", 
    "name" : "Foo Barron", 
    "phone" : "111-222-3333" 
},
{ 
    "_id" : "stack@overflow.com", 
    "name" : "Stack Overflowson", 
    "phone" : "333-222-111" 
}
```

In my angular page I got a field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="vm.searchText" ng-change="vm.search()">
```

And then in my angular controller I want to auto search when the user types in e.g. 3 chars, like `foo` - The angular controller should then call my nodejs controller and get a result.

My nodejs controller receives the `foo` and then what.....?

I would of cause like to look at `_id`, `name` and `phone` to see if `foo` is inside any of them.

db.users.find( .... )

How would you do that?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Neil's excellent solution the search works, but I am having problems setting up the query...

```
    if (received.user) {
        user  = { "_id":   { "$regex": "^" + received.user,  "$options": "i" } }
    }
    if (received.name) {
        name  = { "_id":   { "$regex": "^" + received.name,  "$options": "i" } }
    }
    if (received.phone) {
        phone  = { "_id":   { "$regex": "^" + received.phone,  "$options": "i" } }
    }


    usersTable.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "$or": [
                user,
                name,
                phone
            ] 
        }
    }, etc...
```

Comment: For a couple of characters the best option would be a `$regex` search on the fields using `$or`. And the search "should" be "anchored" from the beginning of the string as in `.find({ "$or": [{ "_id": { "$regex": "^foo", "$options": "i" } }, { "name": { "$regex": "^foo", "$options": "i" } }, { "phone": { "$regex": "^foo", "$options": "i" } }] })`. Of course you should be using MongoDB 3.4 to allow a case insensitive index, otherwise an index cannot really be used by a case insensitive query. And before you ask, a `$text` search does not work with word fragments.

Comment: Neil my man! :)  Great example, I will try it out.  Question, what is `"$options": "i"` ?  and what do you mean by `$text` and word fragments?

Comment: Ahh "Case insensitivity to match upper and lower cases" - got it.  And $text performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a text index.  Ok I will definitely try your suggestion with `$regex`

Comment: A true "text search" as opposed to a "regular expression search" only matches "words". So "foo" is not a "word". If you want to search with a debounce or similar based on "fragments" ( which happens as you type ) then you want a "regex" search. The important thing is the anchor `^` from start of string and using the new index and collation. Otherwise case insensitive searches actually scan the whole collection. And therefore are not fast at all.

Comment: Ohh important to remember the ^ anchor then.  And I want them to search for email address and text with space and phone numbers as well, so the regex is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: @NeilLunn the search you gave me works perfectly!!  Please write a reply so I can give you credits :)  And if its ok, I added a little follow up question that I hope you can help with. (still have problems messing with those json query structures)